# How to generate a scatter plot from a .csv file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to generate a plot of some data held in a .csv file. If I dump the data into Excel, I can generate the following plot:

[image]

This is what the data looked like when it was originally recorded, so Excel seems to be doing the job. So, now I want to run some analysis in SciPy. I can parse the .csv file fine, and the data end up in my arrays in the right order.

```py
while True:
    line = infile.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    else:
        data = re.findall('[\d.]+, line)
        datax.append(data[0])
        datay.append(data[1])
```

When I try to `plt.plot(datax, datay)`, I get something like this:

[image]

I haven't cleaned up the axes or really formatted the plot, but the data structure in the plot is all wrong.

So far, the pyplot images are the same regardless of the plotting technique I try:

- `plt.plot(datax, datay)`
- `plt.scatter(datax, datay)`
- Plotting the data one point at a time: `plt.plot(data[0], data[1])`

If I print out `datax` and `datay`, the elements are in the proper order as they are in the csv file.  I've also tried various techniques for sorting the data that I found here on Stack Overflow. Nothing seems to change the situation.

Comment: Your data needs to be converted to numbers. For example `datax.append(float(data[0]))`.

Comment: You didn't share your CSV, or a representative part of it to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As told in comments above, you are plotting a list of strings against a list of strings

[image]

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import show, subplots
from math import sin

# a CSV file is simply a string, here we have for each line "x, sin(x/42)"
data = '\n'.join(["%f %f"%(x, sin(x/42)) for x in range(0, 801, 10)])

# split the string into lines, split the line into 2 strings
x0, y0 = zip(*[line.split() for line in data.split('\n')])
# otherwise
#        zip(*[line.split() for line in open('xy.csv')])
# split the string into lines, split the line into 2 strings, convert them to floats
x1, y1 = zip(*[[float(xy) for xy in line.split()] for line in data.split('\n')])

# compare 1st plot with your result, 2nd plot with your expectations
fig, (ax0, ax1)  = subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 3), layout='constrained')
ax0.scatter(x0, y0, s=3, c='r') ; ax0.set_title('CSV not converted to floats')
ax1.scatter(x1, y1, s=3, c='g') ; ax1.set_title('CSV converted to floats')

show()
```